# How to remove primary key column in ecto elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

When I use remove key in migration it was not delete the constraint in the table it only delete column name. Please help how can i create for that migration file.

```
defmodule ControlCenter.Repo.Migrations.CreateRemedyTable do
use Ecto.Migration

def up do
  create table(:remedy, primary_key: false) do
     add :remedy_code, :string, primary_key: true
     add :description, :string
     add :cause_code, :string, primary_key: true

  end
 end

 def down do
    drop table(:remedy)
 end
end
```

I want to remove cause_code from the table

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the column, you'll need to [alter](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#alter/2) the table to remove the column after modifying it to not be part of the composite primary key:

```
alter table("remedy") do
  modify(:cause_code, primary_key: false)
  remove(:cause_code)
end
```

If you're deleting it for this migration, add it in the `up` function. If you're deleting it as a one-off, you can `import Ecto.Query` and do the above in `iex -S mix`. Keep in mind, there's not a good solution for migrating back down with a column removal, especially when it was part of a composite key.